# Amazon SP-API authentication

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use the Amazon SP-API to make test calls via Postman. I have an application that can make API requests but it is not in the Amazon app marketplace. I have seen you can make Grantless requests that utilize the  LWA token though I am stuck on making the actual call. Below is the call I am using to get the token.

URL: https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token
Authorization: AWS Signature
I add the requisite keys
In the body I add
grant_type: client_credentials,
client_id: myclientid,
client_secret: myclientsecret,
scope: sellingpartnerapi::notifications
'''
"access_token": "mytoken",
"scope": "sellingpartnerapi::notifications",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3600
'''

Once I get that response I want to make a test call to retrieve orders using this URL

URL: https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders

I am then lost as to how to authenticate that call to get the orders.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same.

Comment: @Martina no it was never solved, the project never completed so we dropped the requirement to use the SP-API.

Comment: Take a look at my lady questione, I think I solved

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it all working in Postman using this as a quote / template.

https://github.com/ionafan2/selling-partner-api-postman-sandbox

Comment: Thanks for adding that. That worked for me. Now I just need to add the Restricted Data Token from inside Postman for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi, can you help me out? I downloaded your postman collection, and managed to successfully call AssumeRole using my AccessKey and SecretKey. However I'm still lost because the only other request in your collection is GetAccessToken, and that requires the refresh token as parameter. And I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the refresh token. I have the following: Role ARN, AccessKey, SecretKey, ClientId, ClientSecret, plus the tokens and keys returned by the AssumeRole call.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full guide (video tutorials included) on how to get SP-API requests working in Postman. I followed it and I succeeded in what I was trying. This guide is part of the updated documentation provided by Amazon about SP-API. You can find what I say at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/using-postman-for-selling-partner-api-models